# Java: Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

Tags: java, tensorflow

I run the code for [java Tensor Flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java) since the Tensor Flow does not support python 3.7.

then the terminal show that `Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2`. I had the python answers but how to deal with java tensor flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using TensorFlow pre-built libraries, which were built on AVX CPU. But now your CPU supports AVX2 so you get this warning.

You can build TensorFlow from source on your PC, by selecting AVX2 while configuring.

Note: it is just a warning, you can ignore it.

Comment: You are so welcome! If you got your answer please vote up and accept the answer, as the regular of SO, to help others get their answers' if they also have the same question. Thanks!